# Inserting tags into soap header using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am processing a soap response file and our requirement is add certain data captured during request to the response. I have this xml reponse here and like a add certain data to the header part of it using a XSLT file. Please advice.

Actual reponse

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-7cd6d5e5">
            <wsu:Created>2009-08-26</wsu:Created>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <GetProxy>
         <ProxiesList/>
      </GetProxy>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Need an xslt to convert this to

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-7cd6d5e5">
            <wsu:Created>2009-08-26</wsu:Created>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
       <ut:reqCode xmlns:ut="temp.org">
       <ut:reqInfo>information from request</ut:reqInfo>
       </ut:reqCode>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <GetProxy>
         <ProxiesList/>
      </GetProxy>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I appreciate you help.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful pattern for inserting things into XML is to use the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) to copy everything and just override it for the tags you want to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
              indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special handling for soap:Header -->
  <xsl:template match="soap:Header">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

      <!-- insert the following inside the soap:Header tag -->
      <ut:reqCode xmlns:ut="temp.org">
        <ut:reqInfo>information from request</ut:reqInfo>
      </ut:reqCode>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This basically just copies everything, but for `soap:Header` after copying its contents, adds some additional content.